# How to enable ansible playbook colors with vagrant?

Tags: ansible, vagrant, vagrantfile

This are my settings from vagrant file:

```
  config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.verbose   = "vv"
    ansible.become    = true # execute as root
    ansible.playbook  = "ansible/playbook.yml"
    # ansible.skip_tags = "once"
    ansible.extra_vars = { ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR: true, ANSIBLE_NO_COLOR: false}
  end
```

This is the output when I run `vagrant up --provision`:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible_local...
    default: Running ansible-playbook...
cd /vagrant && PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR=true ansible-playbook --limit="default" --inventory-file=/tmp/vagrant-ansible/inventory --extra-vars=\{\"ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR\":\"true\",\"ANSIBLE_NO_COLOR\":\"false\"\} --become -vv ansible/playbook.yml
ansible-playbook 2.9.6
```

The colors aren't being displayed in console.

Comment: `extra_vars` is to pass `--extra-vars` to ansible, which are ansible variables, not environment variables. As we can see, the ansible provisioner is explicitly launched with `ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR=true` and the documentation doesn't provide any option to prevent this, so sadly I think it's not possible to use color in this context.

Comment: From the code (https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/74570802f326418f62442090dea9ad8377b052f3/plugins/provisioners/ansible/provisioner/base.rb#L182), you could simply add `--color` option for vagrant to force color in ansible provisioner.

Answer (score 0):

this answer comes maybe a bit late, but for me worked:

```
force_color = True
```

in the
**[defaults]** section of the **/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg**
This is using ansible [core 2.15.5] and Vagrant 2.3.7.